# What is difference between concatenation with an empty string and cast function in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

When I want change numeric variables to string, is there any difference between

```
''||variable
```

and

```
cast(variable as char)
```

?

Comment: `''||variable` is an implicit cast using an concatenation operator.  where as `cast(variable as char)` or `to_char(variable)` are explicit casts.   lets say variable contains a NULL what result would you expect in both situations?  If you expect empty string in the first entry you'd be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The theoretical difference is that one way of converting is implicit while the other is explicit. Implicit conversions should be avoided, when an explicit way is available and just as easy. There are many good reasons for this, which are beyond the scope of your question.

However, there is also a practical difference. The concatenation to the empty string will result in a value of `VARCHAR2` data type. The `CAST` as you wrote it will result in a value of `CHAR(1)` data type. So the two expressions aren't even of the same data type. Worse: the `CAST` will fail if the input is anything other than a single-digit number. This is because `CAST` requires that the width of the result be given; you did not give the width, but for `CHAR` there is a default, of 1. Again, a discussion of the differences between these two data types (there are many such differences) is out of scope.

Best to use `TO_CHAR(..., format_model)`, which gives you full control over the operation. The result is of data type `VARCHAR2`, same as your implicit conversion (concatenation).

Answer (score 0):

`''||variable` is implicit conversion 
and `cast(variable as char(20))` is explicit conversion

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the ending result, but the best thing would be to use existing `TO_CHAR` function:

```
TO_CHAR(variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQL CAST function** converts the data type of an expression to another data type. You can cast an expression to any of the following types: CHAR or CHARACTER: represent a numeric or a string by its initial character.

|| operator concatenates one or more strings into a single string.

Answer (score 0):

If `variable` is defined as say `number` then this declaration will be  `varchar2(40)`:

```
''||variable
```

Whereas this will be `cast(variable as char)` will be `char(1)`:

```
cast(variable as char)
```

In other words, if you want to change the datatype use an explicit `cast()` to do so. But with a data length semantic e.g. cast(variable as char(45))

---

Note, I tested this on 12cR1 - I'd be interested if people using earlier versions get a different outcome.